# Javascript const is assigned with function declaration

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

While making a code review of some npm package I've noticed this pattern:

```
const start = function start() {
   ...code
}
```

I was wondering what this pattern could be useful for. Does anybody know?

Wouldn't be just fine to assign const in this way:

`const start = function() {
   ... code
}`

Comment: what do you ask? why it is `start` mentioned twice?

Comment: It seems that this question really has nothing to do with `const`, even though it's in the title.

Comment: thx @zvona for the reference